# writing data from right to left in file?

Tags: c++

instead of saving data and then reversing it i wanted to know if there is any function that can save the output to the file directly from right to left?
for example if i have this simple code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ofstream fout("filepath");
fout<<"stackoverflow");
return 0;
}
```

instead of having :

```
stackoverflow
```

i want to have:

```
wolfrevokcats
```

*this example is just an example don't be mad at me :D

Comment: reverse the string before writing to file?

Comment: You could probably do something that would reverse the characters within one call to fout<<"blah", but if you need it to reverse all the characters in the file across multiple calls, that would be a lot harder.  I don't think it can be done without buffering up the entire file in memory before writing it.

Comment: There are no "right" and "left" in the file. There are the "beginning" and the "end". No you cannot write from the end to the beginning.

Comment: You could write a recursive function to do it but it would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse the string before writing it. That's the only way I know how to do it because you can't write from "right" to "left"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string thing("my thing");
    std::reverse(thing.begin(), thing.end());
    std::cout << thing << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or wrap the reversed string in a class-based manipulator. [**See it live**](https://ideone.com/jPCXox). And there is no need in this answer's case to copy the string. You could simply use `std::copy(thing.rbegin(), thing.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout,""));`

Comment: +1 on the class manipulator. I chose to write the answer like this because the question conveyed general language inexperience. I figured it would be easier for him/her to understand using "easy" C++ rather than a one-liner :)